# Is there a way to control the order in which different elements render when making a tikz pgf graph?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am creating several handouts for students, and I've noticed the elements of my graphs appear in an order that can be distracting. Here is a zoomed-in picture where you can see what I mean. The circle at x=-2 is supposed to be a hole in the graph, but it appears under the line. The same applies to the line at y=0 and the grid itself. It seems that the elements are rendered in the exact opposite order I need.
[image: Overlap]
Is there a way to control the order, so the grid is under everything, y=0 is over the axis (so there's no black line in the middle), and the two circles are on top of everything? My code for this graph is as follows:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\pgfplotsset{vasymptote/.style={
    before end axis/.append code={
        \draw[densely dashed, magenta] ({rel axis cs:0,0} -| {axis cs:#1,0})
        -- ({rel axis cs:0,1} -| {axis cs:#1,0});
    }
}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \def\FunctionF(#1){(#1+2)/((#1)^2-4)}
      \def\FunctionG(#1){0}
      \begin{axis}[
        axis y line=center,
        axis x line=middle, 
        axis on top=false,
        xmin=-6.5, xmax=6.5,
        ymin=-6.5, ymax=6.5,
        grid,
        xtick={-6,...,6},
        ytick={-6,...,6},
        yticklabels={-6,,-4,,-2,,,,2,,4,,6},
        xticklabels={-6,,-4,,-2,,,,2,,4,,6},
        vasymptote=2,
        ]

        % Hole
        \coordinate (A) at (-2,-1/4);   
        % y-intercept        
        \coordinate (B) at (0,-1/2);

        % Hole 
        \draw[magenta, thick, fill=white] (A) circle (2pt);
        % y-intercept        
        \filldraw[magenta, thick] (B) circle (2pt);

        % f(x)
        \addplot [domain=-7:2-0.1, samples=50, ultra thick, darkgray] {\FunctionF(x)};
        \addplot [domain=2+0.1:7, samples=50, ultra thick, darkgray] {\FunctionF(x)};
        \node [right, darkgray, thick] at (axis cs: 3,2) {$f(x)$};

        %g(x)
        \addplot [domain=-7:7, samples=20, ultra thick, magenta, densely dashed] {\FunctionG(x)};
      \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is caused by `axis on top=true,`. You can change the order of drawing, see section **4.27.3 Changing the Layer of Graphical Elements** of pgfplots manual v1.16.

Comment: Thank you! I missed the `axis on top=true`. Could you elaborate on the changing layers? I've read through the manual section you recommended and cannot seem to make use of the documentation. I've tried what I think should work, but still nothing. My circles are still showing up under the graph line.

Comment: I've updated the code to represent my current state.

Comment: What ordering would you like to achieve? When I compile the above, the grid is in the background, and the asymptote is clearly visible. What would you like to change? (Off-topic: please use `circle[radius=2pt]` instead of `circle(2pt)`.)

Comment: You got it in your answer. I was looking for the grid to be in the background, then the function lines, and then the circles. Thank you for the comment about the circles too. I'm always looking to improve my code with best practices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way how you can use layers. Add `set layers` and draw the circles in the `axis foreground` layer, say,

```
\begin{pgfonlayer}{axis foreground}
    \draw[magenta, thick, fill=white] (A) circle[radius=2pt];
    % y-intercept        
    \filldraw[magenta, thick] (B) circle [radius=2pt];
\end{pgfonlayer}
```

Full example

```
\documentclass[12pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\pgfplotsset{vasymptote/.style={
    before end axis/.append code={
        \draw[densely dashed, magenta] ({rel axis cs:0,0} -| {axis cs:#1,0})
        -- ({rel axis cs:0,1} -| {axis cs:#1,0});
    }
}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \def\FunctionF(#1){(#1+2)/((#1)^2-4)}
      \def\FunctionG(#1){0}
      \begin{axis}[
        axis y line=center,
        axis x line=middle, 
        axis on top=false,
        xmin=-6.5, xmax=6.5,
        ymin=-6.5, ymax=6.5,
        grid,
        xtick={-6,...,6},
        ytick={-6,...,6},
        yticklabels={-6,,-4,,-2,,,,2,,4,,6},
        xticklabels={-6,,-4,,-2,,,,2,,4,,6},
        vasymptote=2,
        set layers%<- added
        ]

        % Hole
        \coordinate (A) at (-2,-1/4);   
        % y-intercept        
        \coordinate (B) at (0,-1/2);

        % Hole 
        \begin{pgfonlayer}{axis foreground}
        \draw[magenta, thick, fill=white] (A) circle[radius=2pt];
        % y-intercept        
        \filldraw[magenta, thick] (B) circle [radius=2pt];
        \end{pgfonlayer}

        % f(x)
        \addplot [domain=-7:2-0.1, samples=50, ultra thick, darkgray] {\FunctionF(x)};
        \addplot [domain=2+0.1:7, samples=50, ultra thick, darkgray] {\FunctionF(x)};
        \node [right, darkgray, thick] at (axis cs: 3,2) {$f(x)$};

        %g(x)
        \addplot [domain=-7:7, samples=20, ultra thick, magenta, densely dashed] {\FunctionG(x)};
      \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You could also just draw the circles after the plots.

```
    \addplot [domain=-7:2-0.1, samples=50, ultra thick, darkgray] {\FunctionF(x)};
    \addplot [domain=2+0.1:7, samples=50, ultra thick, darkgray] {\FunctionF(x)};
    \node [right, darkgray, thick] at (axis cs: 3,2) {$f(x)$};

    %g(x)
    \addplot [domain=-7:7, samples=20, ultra thick, magenta, densely dashed] {\FunctionG(x)};
    % Hole 
    \draw[magenta, thick, fill=white] (A) circle[radius=2pt];
    % y-intercept        
    \filldraw[magenta, thick] (B) circle [radius=2pt];
```

Comment: That's it! When I read the documentation, it looked to me like you had to add something to the `\begin{axis}[]` and then an ordering tag inside the `\addplot`. I also understood that it auto ordered certain elements by type. I didn't realize their order I entered them in the text made a difference. Solved!